# Job Scheduling with O(nlogn)

Tags: c

I'm solving a job scheduling problem with only the deadline and cost for not doing the task, my professor asked me to do in O(nlogn) but so far i just can do it in O(n^2), i already tried to use only merge sort to give me the right sequence of jobs but i cannot find the right way.
Heres my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int p[n]; //Represents the deadline of the tasks
    int m[n]; //Represents the cost of the tasks

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &m[i]);

    merge_sort(p, m, 0, n-1); //Sort the array by the cost of task

    int slots[n+1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        slots[i] = -1;
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = p[i]; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (slots[j] == -1) {
                slots[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (j == 0)
                total += m[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Here some inputs that need to work:

```
n = 3
p[n] = 1 2 3
m[n] = 10 4 12
Output = 0;
n = 4
p[n] = 1 1 1 1
m[n] = 10 12 13 20
Output = 35
n = 5
p[n] = 3 2 2 1 5
m[n] = 4 4 3 3 2
Output = 3
```

Comment: OT: But please get yourself used to ***not*** use one-based indexing. In C it's just a bad habit. If you have input that is one-based, subtract one to make it zero-based.

Comment: Oh and with the loop `for(int j=p[i];j>=0;j--)` you will use `slots[0]`, which you never initialize. It will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Is `O(NlogN)` a requirement? There is an `O(N)` solution...

Comment: @Dalton Gomes, Aside: why code `int p[n]; //Represents the deadline of the tasks` and not use the clearer `int task_deadline[n];`?

Comment: O(nlogn) is the max time complexity required